# Dockerfile with entrypoint for executing bash script

Tags: bash, elasticsearch, docker, dockerfile

I downloaded docker files from official repository (version 2.3), and now I want to build the image and upload some local data (`test.json`) into the container. It is not enough just to run `COPY test.json /usr/share/elasticsearch/data/`, because in this case the indexing of data is not done.

What I want to achieve is to be able to run `sudo docker run -d -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -v /home/gosper/tests/tempESData/:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data test/elasticsearch`, and after its execution I want to be able to see the mapped data on `http://localhost:9200/tests/test/999`.

If I use the below-given Dockerfile and *sh script, then I get the following error: `Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused`

This is the Dockerfile from which I build the image:

```
FROM java:8-jre

# grab gosu for easy step-down from root
ENV GOSU_VERSION 1.7
RUN set -x \
    && wget -O /usr/local/bin/gosu "https://github.com/tianon/gosu/releases/download/$GOSU_VERSION/gosu-$(dpkg --print-architecture)" \
    && wget -O /usr/local/bin/gosu.asc "https://github.com/tianon/gosu/releases/download/$GOSU_VERSION/gosu-$(dpkg --print-architecture).asc" \
    && export GNUPGHOME="$(mktemp -d)" \
    && gpg --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys B42F6819007F00F88E364FD4036A9C25BF357DD4 \
    && gpg --batch --verify /usr/local/bin/gosu.asc /usr/local/bin/gosu \
    && rm -r "$GNUPGHOME" /usr/local/bin/gosu.asc \
    && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/gosu \
    && gosu nobody true

# https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-repositories.html
# https://packages.elasticsearch.org/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys 46095ACC8548582C1A2699A9D27D666CD88E42B4

ENV ELASTICSEARCH_VERSION 2.3.4
ENV ELASTICSEARCH_REPO_BASE http://packages.elasticsearch.org/elasticsearch/2.x/debian

RUN echo "deb $ELASTICSEARCH_REPO_BASE stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elasticsearch.list

RUN set -x \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends elasticsearch=$ELASTICSEARCH_VERSION \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV PATH /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin:$PATH

WORKDIR /usr/share/elasticsearch

RUN set -ex \
    && for path in \
        ./data \
        ./logs \
        ./config \
        ./config/scripts \
    ; do \
        mkdir -p "$path"; \
        chown -R elasticsearch:elasticsearch "$path"; \
    done

COPY config ./config

VOLUME /usr/share/elasticsearch/data

COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /

EXPOSE 9200 9300

RUN chmod +x /docker-entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["elasticsearch"]

COPY template.json /usr/share/elasticsearch/data/

RUN /bin/bash -c "source /docker-entrypoint.sh"
```

This is the `docker-entrypoint.sh` in which I added the line `curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/uniko-documents/document/978-1-60741-503-9 -d "/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/template.json"`:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

# Add elasticsearch as command if needed
if [ "${1:0:1}" = '-' ]; then
    set -- elasticsearch "$@"
fi

# Drop root privileges if we are running elasticsearch
# allow the container to be started with `--user`
if [ "$1" = 'elasticsearch' -a "$(id -u)" = '0' ]; then
    # Change the ownership of /usr/share/elasticsearch/data to elasticsearch
    chown -R elasticsearch:elasticsearch /usr/share/elasticsearch/data

    set -- gosu elasticsearch "$@"
    #exec gosu elasticsearch "$BASH_SOURCE" "$@"
fi

curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/tests/test/999 -d "/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/test.json"

# As argument is not related to elasticsearch,
# then assume that user wants to run his own process,
# for example a `bash` shell to explore this image
exec "$@"
```

Comment: How would the curl succeed? You're running it before you start elasticsearch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the following from your docker-entrypoint.sh:

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/tests/test/999 -d "/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/test.json"
```

It's running before you exec the service at the end.

In your Dockerfile, move the following after any commands that modify the directory:

```
VOLUME /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
```

Once you create a volume, future changes to the directory are typically ignored.

Lastly, in your Dockerfile, this line at the end likely doesn't do what you think, I'd remove it:

```
RUN /bin/bash -c "source /docker-entrypoint.sh"
```

The entrypoint.sh should be run when you start the container, not when you're building it.

Comment: Do you mean this? `VOLUME /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
COPY template.json /usr/share/elasticsearch/data/`  When I use `bash` to enter into the running container and navigate to `data`, I cannot see my `template.json` there.

Comment: Then when I run `bash entrypoint.sh` (this is my script that only has `curl...`), it says `{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse","caused_by":{"type":"not_x_content_exception","reason":"Compressor detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes"}},"status":400}`

Comment: Yes, reverse your VOLUME and COPY order, VOLUME's should be defined near the end after all COPY and RUN commands. From your second comment, you've got the container up, curl is working, the port is reachable, and you're getting an error thrown by the app. That's the end of my knowledge since I know Docker but not elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

@Klue in case you still need it..  you need to change the -d option on your curl command to --data-binary.     -d strips the newlines. that's why you are getting the errors.